# Tweepy giving error on trying to retrieve Tweets by ID

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a list of Tweet IDs that I want to download using Tweepy. I included a sample of them in the list in the code, but I get an error on all of them.

I replaced the tokens and keys with the actual ones and tried using the Tweet IDs as strings and as integers, but both fail. I always get a "No data available for specified ID" error.

```
import tweepy

def download_tweets():

    CONSUMER_KEY = "consumer key"
    CONSUMER_SECRET = "consumer secret"
    OAUTH_TOKEN = "auth token"
    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = "auth token secret"

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    tweets_IDs = [434828570574479360, 434828682352672768, 434828730394230784, 434828787793276928, 434828917174992896, 434829014013067265, 434829430746537985, 434829430746537985, 434829552742068224]

    for id in tweets_IDs:
        tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id)
        print(tweet)
```

The error:

`raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 8, 'message': 'No data available for specified ID.'}]`

Comment: Some tweets might have been deleted, or canceled RT, by their owner.

Answer (score 0):

All but two of those IDs are now invalid. This could mean they were never Tweet IDs, they were Tweets that have now been deleted, the accounts that Tweeted them have been suspended, etc.

You can simply handle the `TweepError` that is raised for each call to `API.get_status`.

Answer (score 0):

There's clearly an error in your code. You are not passing the correct argument value to the function. You are passing **tweet_id** instead of **id**

Here is the working version of your code:

```
import tweepy

    def download_tweets():
    
        CONSUMER_KEY = "consumer key"
        CONSUMER_SECRET = "consumer secret"
        OAUTH_TOKEN = "auth token"
        OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = "auth token secret"
    
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
        tweets_IDs = [434828570574479360, 434828682352672768, 434828730394230784, 434828787793276928, 434828917174992896, 434829014013067265, 434829430746537985, 434829430746537985, 434829552742068224]
    
        for id in tweets_IDs:
            tweet = api.get_status(id)
            print(tweet)
```